# How can I accept standalone blik payment using stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

How can I accept payment via polish blik on stripe? According to the documentation, Blik payment should be a standalone payment option

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  payment_method_types: ['card', 'blik'],
  line_items: [{
    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',
      // To accept `blik`, all line items must have currency: pln
      currency: 'pln',
      product_data: {
        name: 'T-shirt',
      },
      unit_amount: 2000,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
});
```

when I enter blik in the payment_method_types array I get a typescript error

```
Type '"blik"' is not assignable to type 'PaymentMethodType'.ts(2322)
```

Despite that, I tried to create a session as there was an option that silencing TS on one line would do the trick and the checkout session was created, but nothing has happened, no redirect whatsoever, and in the dashboard, I have a session with the status Incomplete and payment method none.

Thanks

Comment: [PaymentMethodType](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/v9.13.0/types/2020-08-27/Checkout/Sessions.d.ts#L2394-L2418) doesn't have 'blik' as a type, so @ts-ignore is probably needed to bypass TypeScript type check. Does your account meet [BLIK compatibility](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/blik/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#compatibility) and enable BLIK in the [payment method page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/payment_methods)?

Comment: In addition, your code has duplicated `payment_method_types` and `line_items[0].price_data.currency` parameters. Could you remove `payment_method_types: ['card']` and `line_items[0].price_data.currency: 'usd'`?

Answer (score 0):

As described in Stripe's docs, all line items must have the currency PLN. The error may be in the stripe SDK version, try using the following:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card', 'blik'],
  line_items: [{
    price_data: {
      // To accept `blik`, all line items must have currency: pln
      currency: 'pln',
      product_data: {
        name: 'T-shirt',
      },
      unit_amount: 2000,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
});
```

Note that definining parameters twice may cause issues, hence why I've removed the duplicate `currency` and `payment_method_types` definitions.

I see that what you've done is directly copy the code in the Stripe docs, note that the red background in the Stripe docs on the page [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/blik/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#compatibility) means that the line should be removed, and green background  means that the line has been added.